# Issues to add the fade Effects in flex by dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, fade

Am trying http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/inproduct/sdk/explorer/explorer.html to add the fade effects in flex by dynamically.But i cannot add the effects,here my code

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init();">
 <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var effect:String;
        private function init():void {
       effect="wipeOutleft";
        }
   ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:WipeLeft id="wipeOutleft" duration="1000"/>
<mx:Image id="img" source="@Embed(source='assets/image002.png')"   mouseDownEffect="{effect}" width="254" height="259"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the `effect` variable bindable:

```
[Bindable]
private var effect:String;
// ...
```

This way, the value of `mouseDownEffect` will be updated when you set a new value (`"wipeOutleft"`) to `effect`.